# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import" error when running tests

Tags: node.js, jestjs, pact

New to Pact JS and Jest for testing API contracts between consumer and provider. I'm trying to setup following some examples.

When running my tests, I face the following issue:

```
<...>/node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-node/src/pact.ts:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import _ = require("underscore");
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:305:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-node/src/index.js:3:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/pact/src/dsl/verifier.js:8:24)
```

Here is what I'm importing:

```
const Pact = require('pact')
const wrapper = require('@pact-foundation/pact-node/src/index.js')
const path = require('path')
```

Comment: Any reason why you aren't importing pact node like `const wrapper = require('@pact-foundation/pact-node')`? It appears to be complaining about typescript source.

Comment: @matthew-fellows: I did try: const wrapper = require('@pact-foundation/pact-node'). Sorry should've mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

is this a javascript or a typescript project?  Seems like your jest is trying to include the typescript from our package into what would be a javascript test project, which then fails on the 'import' since there's no concept of import in javascript, that is, unless you compile it down to javascript.

Isn't jest meant to be used for front-end projects?  Pact-node is made for node projects, not front-end.  You'd want to spin up pact-node before starting the jest test, then use pact-js to communicate with the pact service to setup your interactions.

Comment: can we just use jest and pact to test a front-end project? I'm new to this and having difficulty. I've tried a few examples, but I'm encountering a lot of problem.

I'm now running into the following issues: 
1) Pact verification failed
2) Actual interactions do not match expected interactions for mock MockService.
This seems to be caused around the provider.verify() call. Could you possibly shed some light into the problem?

Comment: @user8901251 could you provide a working example somewhere?  Kind of hard to debug your issue without any code to rely on.  Your feedback about your difficulty is noted; as a whole, we need to work on getting better documentation and examples going.

Comment: Here is the sample gist file i'm using. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dca87a177e88503efe01155c04747cfe

As I said before, would be glad to receive any help.

Comment: Yeah, you're definitely trying to run a node server in a browser environment.  To use the pact mock server through pact-node, you need to spin it up before jest starts running.  I tried to look at the config for jest, which some frameworks has a way to spin up external tools before going through the tests, but I can't seem to find anything in jest.  Instead, you could use the command line (or whatever you use to spin up jest, like Gulp), to would then create the pact-node service.  Using command line, you could do `pact-node mock --port 1234 && jest`.  Is that clear?